# How to "transfer" an ongoing gesture from a subview to the superview without interruption?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview, uiscrollview, uigesturerecognizer

This is what I'm trying to do:

I want to start recognizing a gesture in a subview and then, when the finger leaves the subview, let the superview take over and handle the gesture. Is that possible?

[image]

At the moment, the view in which the gesture started "wins". Is there any way to "hand over" a gesture from one view to another "on the fly", without lifting the finger off the screen?

This is the code for a simple demo:

```
@implementation SPWKViewController {
    UIView *_innerView;
    UIPanGestureRecognizer *_outerGestureRecognizer;
    UIPanGestureRecognizer *_innerGestureRecognizer;

    UILabel *_label;
}

- (void)loadView
{
    [super loadView];

    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];

    _innerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50, 50, self.view.frame.size.width - 100, 200)];
    _innerView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
    _innerView.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];

    _label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 300, self.view.frame.size.width, 40)];
    _label.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
    _label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    _label.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

    [self.view addSubview:_innerView];
    [self.view addSubview:_label];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    _outerGestureRecognizer = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleGesture:)];
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:_outerGestureRecognizer];

    _innerGestureRecognizer = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleGesture:)];
    [_innerView addGestureRecognizer:_innerGestureRecognizer];
}

- (void)handleGesture:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer
{
    if (gestureRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged) {
        if (gestureRecognizer == _outerGestureRecognizer) {
            _label.text = @"outer";
        } else {
            _label.text = @"inner";
        }
    } else {
        _label.text = @"";
    }
}

@end
```

Some background information: The actual problem I'd like to solve is this: I'd like to put a UIWebView inside of a UIScrollView. When I scroll to the bottom of the UIWebView, I want the parent UIScrollView to "take over" and keep scrolling without having to lift the finger off the screen first. I figured that in order to achieve that, I'd need to "hand over" the gesture from the UIWebView to the parent UIScrollView.

Thank you!

Comment: I know that you can just put a UIScrollView inside a UIScrollView and this behaviour "Just Works". I take it you've determined this is not the case for a UIWebView?

Comment: I had a quite similar question (http://stackoverflow.com/q/21554327/235297) and came to the conclusion that it's not possible. But I also thought that `UIWebView`, containing a `UIScrollView` would automatically "trigger" the outer scroll view as soon as it hits the edge, so that the outer scroll view would scroll as well. Doesn't it do that?