# Forward touches to a UIScrollView

Tags: ios, iphone, cocoa-touch, uiscrollview, uigesturerecognizer

I have two view controllers. View controller A has a `UIScrollView` and presents view controller B. The presentation is interactive and controlled by the `scrollView.contentOffset`.

I want to integrate an interactive dismiss transition: When panning up, ViewController B should be dismissed interactively. The interactive dismiss transition should also control the ViewController A scrollView.

My first attempt was using a `UIPanGestureRecognizer` and setting the `scrollView.contentOffset` according to the panned distance. This works, however when the pan gesture is ended, the scrollView offset has to be animated to the end position. Using `-[UIScrollView setContentOffset:animated:` is not a good solution since it uses a linear animation, doesn't take the current pan velocity into account and doesn't decelerate nicely.

So I thought it should be possible to feed the touch events from my pan gesture recognizer into the scroll view. This should give us all the nice scroll view animation behavior.

I tried overriding the `-touchesBegan/Moved/Ended/Cancelled withEvent:` methods in my `UIPanGestureRecognizer` subclass like this:

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    [scrollView touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
    [scrollView.panGestureRecognizer touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];

    [super touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
}
```

But apparently something is blocking the scroll view from entering `tracking` mode. (It does go to `dragging = YES` but that's about it.) I verified the scrollView is `userInteractionEnabled`, not hidden and added to the view hierarchy.

So how can I forward my touch events to `UIScrollView`?

Comment: A workaround suggestion, maybe you can update `contentOffset` without animation from your pan gesture manually?

Comment: That's what I'm doing in the interactive part of the transition. However when I flick the VC B view, I've to continue the animation non-interactively.

Comment: If I understand well, you have a viewController B in the scrollview of A ? And your viewController B is manipulated by a UIPanGesture ? So if you go up, it makes the viewController B disappear and scroll A in the same time ?

Comment: @AncAinu, no, both view controllers are independent and VC B is presented modally on A. When panning up, VC B is dismissed interactively. When the pan gesture recognizer fires, `dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion:` is called which calls `-startInteractiveTransition:` which adds the VC A scroll view back to the container. From this point, I'd like to forward the touch events to the scroll view.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

After reading an [interesting answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/844627/235297) describing `UIScrollView`'s event flow, I came to the conclusion that trying to "remote control" a scroll view from a gesture recognizer is probably very hard to achieve because touches are mutated while being routed to views and gesture recognizers. Since `UITouch` doesn't conform to `NSCopying` we also can't clone touch events in order to send them later in unmodified state.

While not really solving the problem I asked for, I found a workaround to accomplish what I need. I just added a scroll view to view controller B and synced it with VC A's scroll view (which is added to the view hierarchy when vertically scrolling):

```
// delegate of VC B's scrollView
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView*)scrollView
    scrollViewA.contentOffset = scrollView.contentOffset;
}
```

Thanks to Friedrich Markgraf who [came up with the idea](https://twitter.com/fzwob/status/430702167511797760).

Comment: Awarding the tick to my own answer despite not really solving but only working around the issue. Happy to switch the tick to any actually working answer!

Answer (score 3):

Try subclassing the `UIScrollView` and overriding `hitTest:withEvent:` so that the `UIScrollView` picks up touches outside its bounds. Then you get all the nice `UIScrollView` animations for free. Something like this:

```
@interface MagicScrollView : UIScrollView
@end

@implementation MagicScrollView

- (UIView *)hitTest:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    // Intercept touches 100pt outside this view's bounds on all sides. Customize this for the touch area you want to intercept
    if (CGRectContainsPoint(CGRectInset(self.bounds, -100, -100), point)) {
        return self;
    }
    return nil;
}

@end
```

Or in Swift (Thanks Edwin Vermeer!)

```
class MagicScrollView: UIScrollView {
    override func hitTest(point: CGPoint, withEvent event: UIEvent?) -> UIView? {
        if CGRectContainsPoint(CGRectInset(self.bounds, -100, -100), point) {
            return self
        }
        return nil
    } 
}
```

You may also need to override `pointInside:withEvent:` on the `UIScrollView`'s superview, depending on your layout.

See the following question for more info: [interaction beyond bounds of uiview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5432995/interaction-beyond-bounds-of-uiview)

Comment: And for Swift you can use:
class MagicScrollView: UIScrollView {
    override func hitTest(point: CGPoint, withEvent event: UIEvent?) -> UIView? {
        if CGRectContainsPoint(CGRectInset(self.bounds, -100, -100), point) {
            return self
        }
        return nil
    }
}

Comment: Thanks @EdwinVermeer! Added the swift version to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

As an addition to solution of @johnboiles. When you catch the entire rect, then touches on elements inside the scrollview will be skipped. You could add aditional touch areas and for the normal scrollview just pass it on to the super.hitTest like this:

```
class MagicScrollView: UIScrollView {
    override func hitTest(point: CGPoint, withEvent event: UIEvent?) -> UIView? {
        if CGRectContainsPoint(CGRect(x: self.bounds.origin.x - 30, y: self.bounds.origin.y, width: 30, height: self.bounds.size.height), point) {
            return self
        }
        if CGRectContainsPoint(CGRect(x: self.bounds.origin.x + self.bounds.size.width, y: self.bounds.origin.y, width: 30, height: self.bounds.size.height), point) {
            return self
        }
        return super.hitTest(point, withEvent: event)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a scrollview inside of a superview to have left and right borders. To make those borders scrollable, this were my approach :

```
class CustomScrollView: UIScrollView {
  override func hitTest(point: CGPoint, withEvent event: UIEvent?) -> UIView? {
    if let view = super.hitTest(point, withEvent: event) {
      return view
    }

    guard let superview = superview else {
      return nil
    }

    return superview.hitTest(superview.convertPoint(point, fromView: self), withEvent: event)
  }

  override func pointInside(point: CGPoint, withEvent event: UIEvent?) -> Bool {
    if super.pointInside(point, withEvent: event) {
      return true
    }

    guard let superview = superview else {
      return false
    }

    return superview.pointInside(superview.convertPoint(point, fromView: self), withEvent: event)
  }
}
```

Works perfectly