# Nested scrollview with Vertical scrolling for both

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview

I have One scrollview, in that I have another scrollview. 
When nested scrollview offset is 0, then I want main scrollview to start scrolling again & scroll down.

I am able to scroll inner scrollview up by disabling its scrolling & enable scrolling again when inner scrollview completes scrolling.
Issue arises when I have to scroll down, it does not scroll down outer scrollview.
Any suggestions will be highly appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: This looks the same [How to Make the scroll of a TableView inside ScrollView behave naturally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33292427/how-to-make-the-scroll-of-a-tableview-inside-scrollview-behave-naturally)

Comment: Thank you @Erumaru for the link. I was able to solve my issue.

Comment: I'm glad to hear that :)